# onMouseOver event on an image array is getting called only once in gwt

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I have an image array attached to a DeckPanel. What I want is to have a pop-up on mouse hover on images which vanishes on mouseOut.

Code is as follows :

```java
final PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel();
        for(int i=0; i<images.size();++i){
            final int index = i;
            image[i] = new Image(images.get(i));
            image[i].addMouseOutHandler(new MouseOutHandler(){

                @Override
                public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    popup.hide();
                }});
            image[i].addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler(){

                @Override
                public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Label label = new Label(images.get(index));
                    popup.add(label);
                    popup.showRelativeTo(image[index]);
                }});
            image[i].addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Window.alert("image clicked");
                }});
            deck.add(image[i]);
        }
```

Problem : onMouseOver() is  getting only once. Could you guys please help me understand whats happening here and how tell me how to make it work for all images every time dat image is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onMouseOver you are repeatedly adding label to the popup.PopupPanel is a SimplePanel it can add only one widget.So onMouserOver first clear the PopupPanel

```
popup.clear();
Label label = new Label(images.get(index));
popup.add(label);
popup.showRelativeTo(image[index]);
```